# Error opening playground in development environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I tried tutorial on "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html", and it works fine.
But I couldn't open playground in this environment. I started composer-playground by running "composer-playground" from shell prompt, and I could open Playground GUI on "http://localhot:8080", but several seconds later, I got error "Error: error trying to setup a keystore path. EACCES" on browser, and following error in output of composer-playground. How can I fix this error ?

> HLFConnectionManager     :_setupWallet()            !! _setupWallet,
>   EACCES HLFConnectionManager     :connect()                 !! connect,
>   {"stack":["{Error}error trying to setup a keystore path. EACCES Error:
>   error trying to setup a keystore path. EACCES","    at
>   Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore.then.catch
>   (/home/htanaka/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnectionmanager.js:337:36)","
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)"]}
>   ConnectorServer          :Error: error trying to setup a keystore
>   path. EACCES() !! {"stack":["{Error}error trying to setup a keystore
>   path. EACCES Error: error trying to setup a keystore path. EACCES","
>   at Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore.then.catch
>   (/home/htanaka/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnectionmanager.js:337:36)","
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)"]}

Comment: It's likely that you have something in your browser local storage that isn't compatible with the playground environment you are running. Can you try clearing local storage of the browser or open the playground url in an incognito window in chrome and see if you get the same error ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I reinstalled the cluster, clean browser local storage then it works !